# How to change outline color of Material UI React input component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've searched high and low for an answer, in both the docs and other SO questions.

I'm using the `createMuiTheme` option in a separate JS file to override certain default styling, but am having a hard time understanding how the `overrides` option works.

Currently my button looks like this:
[image]
The code I've got to get this far looks like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    ...other code,
    overrides: {
    MuiFormControlLabel: {
        focused: {
            color: '#4A90E2'
        }
    },
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
        focused: {
                border: '1px solid #4A90E2'
        },
        notchedOutline: {
            border: '1px solid #4A90E2'
        },
    },
    MuiFormLabel: {
        focused: {
            color: '1px solid #4A90E2'
        }
    }
}
)};
```

Then in my component, I'm using it as such:

```
import theme from './styles/ThemeStyles';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

class SignInForm extends Component {
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete='off'>
        <TextField
            id="outlined-email-input"
            label="Email"
            className={classes.textField}
            type="email"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            margin="normal"
            variant="outlined"
        />
    </form>
}}
```

My question is, what am I missing to make my component look so funky? And in the future, how do I know what to target in the `overrides` option of the ThemeProvider so that I don't run into similar situations?

Comment: I answered the question but you may want to file a bug with Material UI, I don't think it's intentional that they don't have notched outline specific styling that's passed through the outlinedinput for the various states.

Comment: Seems they may have fixed the docs now... see [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55820364/1062992).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to Rudolf Olah's help and pointing me in the right direction! I was able to solve the issue with the following code:

```
overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
        root: {
            position: 'relative',
            '& $notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)',
            },
            '&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: '#4A90E2',
                // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
                '@media (hover: none)': {
                    borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)',
                },
            },
            '&$focused $notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: '#4A90E2',
                borderWidth: 1,
            },
        },
    },
    MuiFormLabel: {
        root: {
            '&$focused': {
                color: '#4A90E2'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice work! it isn't obvious from the Material UI documentation that all sorts of CSS selectors can be used.

Comment: So true. I started out with Semantic UI and had issues with responsiveness, but Material UI is giving me its own headaches.

Comment: '&:hover $notchedOutline' (i.e. $notchedOutline) was the thing I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

To find the class names and CSS properties that you can change, [the documentation for the Component API shows a list](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/).

`TextField` is a special case though, because it combines and renders multiple sub-components, it allows you to pass CSS properties to the `Input` component and the `FormHelperText` component.

And the [OutlinedInput](https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/) is a very special case, because it actually uses [NotchedInput](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput/NotchedOutline.js) for the input element which has its own CSS properties.

Looking at the [code for the OutlinedInput](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js#L17-L38) you can see child selectors being used:

```js
root: {
  position: 'relative',
  '& $notchedOutline': {
    borderColor,
},
// ...
```

*It looks like the issue is that the OutlinedInput doesn't set the styles for the NotchedOutline correctly*

You may have some luck with this:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  // ...other code,
  overrides: {
    // ...
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      focused: {
        border: '1px solid #4A90E2'
      },
      '& $notchedOutline': {
        border: '1px solid #4A90E2'
      },
    },
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the very good and thorough answer! It appears as though nothing has changed with the styling of the input from the image I included in my original post though, unfortunately. I wonder if I might have some other styles somehow overwriting it? I know that before I was able to give it a blue border and was using the `overrides` property, that the focused state of the input was white for some reason.

Comment: @J.Jackson I actually tried another approach, using `withStyles` to wrap the element, however that didn't quite work either. You may want to consider creating your own outlined input that's a subclass of `OutlinedInput` that correctly styles the notchedOutline. I think a custom component may be the best option.

Answer (score 6):

This is covered in the docs pretty well [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#customized-inputs).

Click inside the field labelled "Custom CSS" for a demo.

Here's how this could be done using your original `TextField` component:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

const styles = theme => ({
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    marginBottom: '0px',
  },
  label: {
    '&$focused': {
      color: '#4A90E2'
    },
  },
  focused: {},
  outlinedInput: {
    '&$focused $notchedOutline': {
      border: '1px solid #4A90E2'
    },
  },
  notchedOutline: {},
})

const CustomOutline = ({classes}) => (
  <TextField
    id="outlined-email-input"
    label="Email"
    className={classes.textField}
    type="email"
    name="email"
    autoComplete="email"
    margin="normal"
    variant="outlined"
    InputLabelProps={{
      classes: {
        root: classes.label,
        focused: classes.focused,
      },
    }}
    InputProps={{
      classes: {
        root: classes.outlinedInput,
        focused: classes.focused,
        notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
      },
    }}
  />
)

CustomOutline.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomOutline)
```

Comment: how to implement this in autocomplete. https://codesandbox.io/s/tfgz5
it only change the lable color

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: The authors of the framework did not really cover this in the docs that well.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/13557