# How to override CSS of MUI Dialog?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to set hight of dialog, but the MUI CSS seems to get higher CSS priority.
How do I use it or override it?

I tried something like this:

```
<Dialog
      classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
..
..
</Dialog>
```

But still my class ".qdidataappseed-makeStyles-paper-..." is lower priority.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876589/material-ui-theme-overrides-how-to-override-children-styles-globally check the comments+answers

Answer (score 1):

It possible to set Dialog component height using sx properties:

```
<Dialog sx={{height: '100px'}}
```

or `minHeight` / `maxHeight` depends on what exactly we need to set.