# Change outline for OutlinedInput with React material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Quick note: this is not a duplicate of [How to change outline color of Material UI React input component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53764626/how-to-change-outline-color-of-material-ui-react-input-component)

With material-ui (React) I am unable to delete the outline on hover or focus. The  reason I am using this input is to request add a little red border when a warning occurs. I can change the focused and hover styles. This is tested in the following image:
[image]

Where this CSS is applied when the input is focused:

```
outlinedInputFocused: {
     borderStyle: 'none',
     borderColor: 'red',
     outlineWidth: 0,
     outline: 'none',
     backgroundColor: 'green'
  },
```

Component

```
 <OutlinedInput
            disableUnderline={true}
            notched={true}
            id="adornment-weight"
            classes={{root: classes.outlinedInput, focused: classes.outlinedInputFocused}}
            value={this.state.budgetValue}
            onChange={evt => this.updateBudgetValue(evt)}
            onKeyPress={evt => this.handleKeyPress(evt)}
            endAdornment={<InputAdornment sposition="end">BTC</InputAdornment>}
          />
```

As you can see the color of the image is green, but  there is still an outline. Even though the outlineWidth is 0 and outline is set to none in the CSS. How can I change / disable this outline?

Answer (score 18):

The key to understanding how to override these styles is to look at how they are defined in the Material-UI source code. The question you referenced also shows some of the syntax needed.

Below is an abbreviated version (I left out the styles that are not related to the outline) of the styles from [OutlinedInput.js](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js):

```
export const styles = theme => {
  const borderColor =
    theme.palette.type === 'light' ? 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)' : 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.23)';

  return {
    /* Styles applied to the root element. */
    root: {
      position: 'relative',
      '& $notchedOutline': {
        borderColor,
      },
      '&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $notchedOutline': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.text.primary,
        // Reset on touch devices, it doesn't add specificity
        '@media (hover: none)': {
          borderColor,
        },
      },
      '&$focused $notchedOutline': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
        borderWidth: 2,
      },
      '&$error $notchedOutline': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.error.main,
      },
      '&$disabled $notchedOutline': {
        borderColor: theme.palette.action.disabled,
      },
    },
    /* Styles applied to the root element if the component is focused. */
    focused: {},
    /* Styles applied to the root element if `disabled={true}`. */
    disabled: {},
    /* Styles applied to the root element if `error={true}`. */
    error: {},
    /* Styles applied to the `NotchedOutline` element. */
    notchedOutline: {}

  };
};
```

The "outline" of `OutlinedInput` is controlled via the `border` on the [NotchedOutline](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput/NotchedOutline.js) component nested within it. In order to impact that nested element, you need to define a "notchedOutline" class (even if empty) that you can then use to target that element for the different states (e.g. focused, hover) of the parent.

Here's an example that fully removes the border:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import OutlinedInput from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    "& $notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    "&:hover $notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    "&$focused $notchedOutline": {
      borderWidth: 0
    }
  },
  focused: {},
  notchedOutline: {}
});
function App(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <OutlinedInput
        disableUnderline={true}
        notched={true}
        id="adornment-weight"
        classes={classes}
        value={1}
        endAdornment={<InputAdornment sposition="end">BTC</InputAdornment>}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit 94k34o11np]

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline style like this:

```
<MyComponent style={{outline: 'none'}} />
```

Answer (score 1):

2.4.7 Focus Visible: Any keyboard operable user interface has a mode of operation where the keyboard focus indicator is visible. (Level AA)

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible
https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/quickref/?versions=2.0#qr-navigation-mechanisms-focus-visible

Answer (score 0):

`OutlinedInput` is desined in such a way that you can't turn off its outline you have to use `TextField` with `variant` 'outlined' as default and 'none' on focus.
You can see the example of `Outlined Input Adornments` using `TextField` [here](https://material-ui.com/demos/text-fields/#outlined-input-adornments)