# How do I override hover notchedOutline for OutlinedInput

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i upgraded from material ui version 3 to 4 and would like to override:
.MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline

since I think this update introduces the hover state which is changing my current UI.

I used createMuiTheme()

and have tried the following but none of those worked:

```
MuiOutlinedInput: {
    root: {
        '&:hover': {
            '&$notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: '#f00',
            }
        },
    },
}


MuiOutlinedInput: {
    root: {
        '&$hover $notchedOutline': {
            borderColor: '#f00',
        },
    },
}
```

what am I doing wrong, hope someone can help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You were quite close. The correct syntax is a combination of aspects from your two attempts.

The "hover" state is controlled via the ":hover" pseudo-class (it is **not** a rule name as referenced in your second example with `$hover`), so your first example correctly uses `&:hover` to match the hover state of the input; however the `$notchedOutline` class is applied to a descendant of the root element (**not** the root element itself) so you need the space between the root reference and the `$notchedOutline` reference as in your second example.

Here is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        "& $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "green"
        },
        "&:hover $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "red"
        },
        "&$focused $notchedOutline": {
          borderColor: "purple"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField variant="outlined" defaultValue="My Text" />
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit OutlinedInput]

Related answers:

- [Change outline for OutlinedInput with React material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325908/change-outline-for-outlinedinput-with-react-material-ui/54331012#54331012)
- [Global outlined override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789989/global-outlined-override/54794340#54794340)
- [Can't change border color of Material-UI OutlinedInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958742/cant-change-border-color-of-material-ui-outlinedinput/56958994#56958994)

Comment: hi Ryan, argh so close, thanks a lot for pointing out. Hope this can help others as well

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was helpful for me too, if you can tell me how to set the same property using classes obj instead of overwrite