# Change border color on Material-UI TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This should be simple but for some reason I can't figure out how to change the border color on a TextField

```
<TextField style={{ borderColor: 'white', width: '100px' }} variant="outlined" />
```

It's basically just copied from the docs, where on the outline is white, so I can't figure out what might be messing this up on my end.

I tried to reproduce on jsfiddle or something but couldn't find one that would allow me to import the TextField module

[image: screencap]

Comment: TextField  coming from ? what are you suing ?

Comment: @G.aziz my bad, updated question with info, @material-ui/core/TextField

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Below is a v4 example (v5 example further down) of how to override the color of the outline, label, and input text on the outlined variant of `TextField`. This shows using three different colors: one for the default (green), one for hover (red), and a different one when the input has focus (purple).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "green"
    },
    "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "red"
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "purple"
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-input": {
      color: "green"
    },
    "&:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-input": {
      color: "red"
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-input": {
      color: "purple"
    },
    "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
      color: "green"
    },
    "&:hover .MuiInputLabel-outlined": {
      color: "red"
    },
    "& .MuiInputLabel-outlined.Mui-focused": {
      color: "purple"
    }
  }
});

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        className={classes.root}
        defaultValue="My Default Value"
        variant="outlined"
        label="My Label"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField outlined (forked)]

---

Below is a similar example using v5 of MUI. This uses `styled` instead of `makeStyles` and leverages a more type-safe manner (added in v5) for referencing the global class names (e.g. `.${outlinedInputClasses.root}`), but continuing to hard-code the global class names (e.g. `.MuiOutlinedInput-root`) still works fine as well (it's simpler syntax when hard-coded, but less protection from typos and no autocomplete help).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { outlinedInputClasses } from "@mui/material/OutlinedInput";
import { inputLabelClasses } from "@mui/material/InputLabel";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)({
  [`& .${outlinedInputClasses.root} .${outlinedInputClasses.notchedOutline}`]: {
    borderColor: "green"
  },
  [`&:hover .${outlinedInputClasses.root} .${outlinedInputClasses.notchedOutline}`]: {
    borderColor: "red"
  },
  [`& .${outlinedInputClasses.root}.${outlinedInputClasses.focused} .${outlinedInputClasses.notchedOutline}`]: {
    borderColor: "purple"
  },
  [`& .${outlinedInputClasses.input}`]: {
    color: "green"
  },
  [`&:hover .${outlinedInputClasses.input}`]: {
    color: "red"
  },
  [`& .${outlinedInputClasses.root}.${outlinedInputClasses.focused} .${outlinedInputClasses.input}`]: {
    color: "purple"
  },
  [`& .${inputLabelClasses.outlined}`]: {
    color: "green"
  },
  [`&:hover .${inputLabelClasses.outlined}`]: {
    color: "red"
  },
  [`& .${inputLabelClasses.outlined}.${inputLabelClasses.focused}`]: {
    color: "purple"
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledTextField
        defaultValue="My Default Value"
        variant="outlined"
        label="My Label"
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField outlined]

Related answers:

- [Change outline for OutlinedInput with React material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325908/change-outline-for-outlinedinput-with-react-material-ui/54331012#54331012)
- [How do I override hover notchedOutline for OutlinedInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113579/how-do-i-override-hover-notchedoutline-for-outlinedinput/58118702#58118702)
- [Global outlined override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789989/global-outlined-override/54794340#54794340)

Comment: You're the real mvp

Comment: Do you have a solution for `TextArea` or `TextAreaAutoSize`?

Comment: @KelseyHannan I always use those via `TextField` with the `multiline` property where the styling in this answer still works.

Comment: That's a useful tip, though `TextAreaAutoSize` has its advantages for autosizing to the amount of text written in the box.  I cannot believe such a basic feature in MUI is so fragile.

Comment: @KelseyHannan `TextField` uses `TextareaAutosize` internally when you specify the `multiline` property.

Comment: @RyanCogswell Omg your right.  My color outlining issue actually disappeared when I changed `TextAutosize` to `TextField` with the `multiline` property.  Must have been a bug with MUI `5.5.3`   Thank you so much.

Comment: @RyanCogswell The one for v5 works great! Thanks a lot. Now how would I move that exact styling to a scss? Is it possible? I saw you post on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60160225/is-there-a-way-to-style-the-border-color-and-text-color-of-textfield-in-mater/60172973#60172973) but I can't get that to work with this. I'm too new to this. Thanks.

Comment: The solution you have provided is working fine. But i'm curious to understand what css property does the mui use internally and to what element does it apply to to make the border ? I have verified all the nested elements of the TextField but unable to find any element with border related properties.