# Changing Border Color of React Material UI Textfield and Outlined Input

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am having trouble with changing the border color of both the textfield and outlined input components from Material-UI for my registration form. I have looked at solutions posted on SO, but none of them seem to work for my case. I want to have a border color of white as a default and another for when the input is focused.

Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-waterfall-dgq2u

If anyone could help or point me to the right post for this use case, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Man, I would very much like to help you, but please post the code here.

Comment: It's available if you click the code sandbox link

Comment: I know that, but past here just the piece you want us to help you.

Comment: The problem I am having is with the whole component. I can't work out why I am unable to change the border color of the input fields (username and password).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change border color on Material-UI TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963242/change-border-color-on-material-ui-textfield) This also includes the hover and focused settings

Comment: Yes, I found this solution earlier and it worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, maybe so better searching next time before you open a question XD