# How do I over write nested classes of material-ui in styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

```
Method 1:
const StyledTextField = styled(({ ...rest }) => (
  <OutlinedInput {...rest} classes={{ root: 'outlinedRoot' }} />
))`
  .outlinedRoot {
    .$notchedOutline {
      border-color: red;
    }
  }
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #808080;
  height: 53px;
`;

Method 2:
const StyledTextField = styled(OutlinedInput).attrs({
  classes: { root: 'outlinedRoot', notchedOutline: 'notchedOutline' }
})`
  .outlinedRoot {
    .notchedOutline {
      border-color: red;
    }
  }
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: #808080;
  height: 53px;
`;
```

I have seen also what classes needs to be added and read articles about that, but I am not able to overwrite

I tried above two ways to change the outline color but i am not able to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example of one way to do this. To do this with `TextField` rather than `OutlinedInput`, just add a space before `.MuiOutlinedInput-root` so that you match that as a descendant of `TextField` rather than matching that as one of the other classes on the root element. `.MuiOutlinedInput-root` is actually unnecessary for the styling except for helping with CSS specificity.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import OutlinedInput from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledOutlinedInput = styled(OutlinedInput)`
  &.MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: green;
  }
  &:hover.MuiOutlinedInput-root .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: red;
  }
  &.MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: purple;
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StyledOutlinedInput defaultValue="My Default Value" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit custom outline styled-components]

Related answers:

- [Change border color on Material-UI TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963242/change-border-color-on-material-ui-textfield/58963947#58963947)
- [Change outline for OutlinedInput with React material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325908/change-outline-for-outlinedinput-with-react-material-ui/54331012#54331012)
- [How do I override hover notchedOutline for OutlinedInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113579/how-do-i-override-hover-notchedoutline-for-outlinedinput/58118702#58118702)
- [Global outlined override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789989/global-outlined-override/54794340#54794340)