# How can I change border color for Select Component?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How to set the border color for select component in material ui library, 
Under the inspect elements, if i set the property then it works, but how to do this using class override.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't change border color of Material-UI OutlinedInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56958742/cant-change-border-color-of-material-ui-outlinedinput)

Answer (score 0):

There are [multiple ways](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) to re-style material-ui components, here is my preferred method:

```
import {styled, Select} from "@material-ui/core"

const StyledSelect = styled(Select)({
  borderColor: "..."
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use border: '2px solid red' inside style prop like style={{border: '2px solid red'}}