# Is there a way to style the border color and text color of <TextField/> in Material-UI without using makeStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, material-ui

Is it possible to style Material-UI without using the makeStyles feature, for example, css? Just trying to understand how Material-UI style works.

The red style on the bottom is the style I'm trying to achieve with simple css here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how to customize the various colors in an outlined select using simple CSS.

**styles.css**

```
.customSelect {
  width: 200px;
}
.customSelect .MuiInputLabel-root {
  color: red;
}
.customSelect .MuiInputBase-input {
  color: green;
}
.customSelect .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border-color: red;
}
.customSelect:hover .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border-color: orange;
}
.customSelect
  .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused
  .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
  border-color: purple;
}
.customSelectMenu .MuiMenuItem-root {
  color: blue;
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  return (
    <TextField
      className="customSelect"
      label="Sale Type"
      required
      select
      value={value}
      onChange={event => setValue(event.target.value)}
      variant="outlined"
      SelectProps={{ MenuProps: { className: "customSelectMenu" } }}
    >
      <MenuItem value={1}>Sale Type 1</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={2}>Sale Type 2</MenuItem>
    </TextField>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Customize TextField via CSS]

Related answers:

- [Change border color on Material-UI TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963242/change-border-color-on-material-ui-textfield/58963947#58963947)
- [Global outlined override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789989/global-outlined-override/54794340#54794340)
- [Change outline for OutlinedInput with React material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325908/change-outline-for-outlinedinput-with-react-material-ui/54331012#54331012)

Comment: Pardon my nood 2 days efforts with react. How would I do this in V5 and with scss? Can't figure out all the classed dependencies and hierarchy.