# How to change the label color of Material-UI <TextField/>

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I change the color from "email" label and make it the same as the border line?

[image: Example here]

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Divider } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { TextField, Button, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

let self;

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit,
    width: 280
  },
  cssLabel: {
    color: "#d3d3d3"
  },
  cssOutlinedInput: {
    "&:not(hover):not($disabled):not($cssFocused):not($error) $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#d3d3d3" //default
    },
    "&:hover:not($disabled):not($cssFocused):not($error) $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#d3d3d3" //hovered #DCDCDC
    },
    "&$cssFocused $notchedOutline": {
      borderColor: "#23A5EB" //focused
    }
  },
  cssInputLabel: {
    color: "#d3d3d3"
  },
  notchedOutline: {},
  cssFocused: {},
  error: {},
  disabled: {}
});
class NewLoginComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
      user: "",
      errorMsg: "",
      errorMsgLength: "",
      loginErrorMsg: "",
      flag: false,
      password: "",
      hidden: true,
      valuePassText: "SHOW"
    };
    self = this;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    if (this.props.password) {
      this.setState({ password: this.props.password });
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {}

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    let username = "";
    let password = "";
    return (
      <div className="container-fluid backround">
        <div className="container" id="loginform">
          <div className="form-group">
            <div>
              <div className="emailInput">
                <TextField
                  className={classes.textField}
                  id="email-txt-input"
                  label="Email"
                  variant="outlined"
                  inputRef={node => (username = node)}
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.cssLabel,
                      focused: classes.cssFocused
                    }
                  }}
                  InputProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                      focused: classes.cssFocused,
                      notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline
                    },
                    inputMode: "numeric"
                  }}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="passwordInput">
                <TextField
                  className={classes.textField}
                  id="password-txt-input"
                  label="Password"
                  variant="outlined"
                  inputRef={node => (password = node)}
                  type={this.state.hidden ? "password" : "text"}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                  InputLabelProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.cssLabel,
                      focused: classes.cssFocused
                    }
                  }}
                  InputProps={{
                    classes: {
                      root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                      focused: classes.cssFocused,
                      notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline
                    },
                    inputMode: "numeric"
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group form">
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                id="normal-signin-Btn"
                type={"submit"}
                className={"btn btn-primary loginButton"}
              >
                LogIn
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

NewLoginComponent.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NewLoginComponent);
```

[image: Edit thirsty-dust-u4vuz]

Comment: Im guessing ur using https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#textfield ?

.MuiInputLabel-formControl.Mui-focused { color: *Your border-color* }

Comment: Yes click the "1" and you will see the input. But where in my code i will add this that you wrote?

Comment: Its the default color which you want to implement here https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/, You want that to change ?

Comment: yes the default color I want to change.Now it's blue the default color

Comment: If you click at the "Example here" you will see my example and you will see that the Email label it is different color from the other border line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change material UI select border and label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459932/how-to-change-material-ui-select-border-and-label)

Comment: No because I am using a different way to add a custom css in meterial component

Comment: I recommend that you include a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) that reproduces your problem and include the full code of that sandbox in your question.

Comment: Yes you have right @RyanCogswell I have add the code sanbox in the main question up. Thanks a lot.

Comment: or here [MeterialUiExample](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-dust-u4vuz)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is one way to control the focused color of the input label to be the same as the focused color of the border:

```
  cssLabel: {
    color: "#d3d3d3",
    "&.Mui-focused": {
      color: "#23A5EB"
    }
  },
```

[image: Edit romantic-kapitsa-z33pg]

Answer (score 4):

You can simply  use the InputLabelProps in your TextField component , for exemple :

```
<TextField InputLabelProps={{style : {color : 'green'} }}></TextField>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this: put in the TextField

```
sx={{
        "& label": {
          "&.Mui-focused": {
            color: 'your color*'
          }
        }
      }}
```

Comment: I used your solution like this in my code ` <Controller
          name="firstName"
          control={control}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
            <TextField
              label="First Name"
              variant="standard"
              value={value}
              onChange={onChange}
              focused
              sx={(theme) => {
                return {
                  "& label": {
                    "&.Mui-focused": {
                      color: theme.palette.common.white,
                    }  } }; }} /> )} />`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this CSS code in your CSS file to change its border color:

```
.css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline{
color: yellow !important;
border: 2px solid yellow !important;
```

}

and to change its label you can use the following inline style in your `<TextField/>` :

```
InputLabelProps={{style : {color : 'yellow'} }}
```

This method should work if you still can't change it, You can also try changing its color by inspecting it from the browser.